# trouble with parsing datetime.datetime.strptime

Tags: python, csv, datetime, graph, datetime-format

I have a list of 1500 lines of data that look like

> USGS \t 14211720 \t 2017-02-12 22:00 \t PST   \t 117000   \t P    11.96   P

Before I add the datetime line the dischargelist and gagheightList work and give me a count of 1400 lines but when I add the date time to it I get

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list" 
I am trying to pull the date, discharge and height to make two graphs
```

My code:

```
import csv

import datetime

dateList = []
dischargeList = []
gageheightList = []

readCSV = csv.reader(dataLines, delimiter = '\t')

for row in readCSV:
    date_str = [2]
    dateTIME = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str,"%Y,%m,%d T%H:%M")
    dateList.append(dateTIME)

    discharge = row[4]
    dischargeList.append(discharge)
    gageheight = row[6]
    gageheightList.append(gageheight)

#print(dateList)
#this line was just to test if the dates were making it to a list    


print("we have {} items in the date list".format(len(dateList)))

print("we have {} items in thegage height list".format(len(gageheightList)))

print ("we have {} items in the discharge list".format(len(dischargeList)))
```

Comment: `date_str = [2]` should be `date_str = row[2]`

Answer (score 1):

Just as AJPennster said, you should know how to use `datetime` module. The code below is the usage of method `datetime.datetime.strptime(string, format)`

```
import datetime

_str1 = "2017,02,12 22:00"
_str2 = "2017-02-12 22:00"

format_str1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(_str1, "%Y,%m,%d %H:%M")
format_str2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(_str1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

When using `datetime.datetime.strptime(string, format)` method, you should fill your format parameter strictly according to the format of the srting you provided.

Answer (score 0):

`date_str = [2]` sets `date_str` as a list containing `2`.

Which is why when you try to do

`dateTIME = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str,"%Y,%m,%d T%H:%M")`

you get

`TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list"`

Changing `date_str = [2]` to `date_str = row[2]` should solve your problem.

Comment: that did change it but know it says "   ValueError: time data '2017-02-12 18:15' does not match format '%Y,%m,%d T%H:%M'   "

Comment: What do you think that means? Read how to use [strptime](https://pymotw.com/2/datetime/#formatting-and-parsing)